# How to loop(foreach) json decoded in php (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel-5

**This is my code**`

```
$a =json_decode($user->name, true);
```

And I need to loop `$a`, but I'm getting

> "Invalid Argument supplied for foreach"

while executing
`

Comment: Show the code that loops.

Comment: Why would the user name be JSON to begin with? Also see: [mcve].

Comment: @Difster    foreach($a as $akey => $aloop)
{  
array_push($array, $aloop->email));
}

Answer (score 0):

you can loop in array and i think the result of this `$a =json_decode($user->name, true);`

is string

Comment: Result is looks like this 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => abc@gmail.com
            [phone] => 1999999990
            
        )

)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've posted in the other answer and the comment to me, you need to change your loop to this:

```
foreach($a[0] as $akey => $aloop) { array_push($array, $aloop->email)); }
```

Notice the change from `$a` to `$a[0]`

Comment: Please do var_dump($a) and post the results. Redact any sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

You should describe to us how your JSON String look like.

Maybe you can try this code below :

```
$user= '[{"name":"Jonathan Suh","email":"jonathan.suh@gmail.com"},
              {"name":"William Phil","email":"will.phil@gmail.com"},
              {"name":"Allison Kin","email":"allison.kin@gmail.com"}]';

// Replace with your own JSON
$a = json_decode($user, true); // Array

// Create empty array to hold query results
$array = [];

// Begin loop ( foreach )
foreach ($a as $akey => $aloop) {
    array_push($array, ['name' => $aloop["name"], 'email' => $aloop["email"]]);
}

// Encode your array result from Loop Process to JSON
// You can change whatever you want to do from your Result Loop
$jsonENC = json_encode($array);

// You know what is this...
echo $jsonENC;
```